# Adding data retroactively to a binding

Tags: data-binding, polymer

I've been experimenting with a `<firebase-collection>` element that provides data to a `<template is="dom-repeat">`:

```
<firebase-collection id="base" data="{{things}}" location="[…]"></firebase-collection>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{things}}">
    […]
</template>
```

If I use the code above, everything works as expected: the DOM repeat displays and in the JS console, `app.things` is populated.

If I try to either dynamically create the `<firebase-collection>` or change its `location` attribute after the page is loaded, however, neither the DOM repeat nor `app.things` reflects the loaded data. The resulting page source is the same and querying the `.data` property of the `<firebase-collection>` displays the expected results.

Why is this different? Does it have to do with the stamping process for Polymer? How can I dynamically create the collection element later and have it automatically update the other elements that use the data?

Comment: did you add the notify: true to the property?

Comment: Even with properties defined and the `things` property set to `notify: true`, no luck.

Comment: what if you add an observer?

Comment: did it work? adding the observer?